# nativescript Warning : Cannot find a valid certificate or provisioning profile for the iOS platform

Tags: ios, windows, nativescript, provisioning-profile

I am working on windows 10, I have started developing nativescript, and to test apps on IOS, i have installed 'SideKick', but when i am trying to run App on IOS on the cloud, I am getting this warning that prevents me from building IOS

"Cannot find a valid certificate or provisioning profile for the iOS platform"

since I am working on window, and do not have mac or ios phone, from where to get a certificate or a provisioning profile?
thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a paid Apple developer account to build and deploy code signed apps on physical devices.

You should read through the information about code signing for nativescript here: 
https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-ios-apps#account-with-apple-id

You will need to create a development certificate and profile, and add the device IDs for the devices you want to test on.

Comment: i just want to test on an emulator on the cloud, do i still need to have  certificate?

Comment: I'm not aware of any successful iOS emulators in the cloud.  Most cloud testing services offer physical iOS devices that are shared that allow you to run your apps on. If you are running on emulated (or more likely simulated) iOS devices in the cloud, they should not require code signing.  Can you share the cloud service you are trying to test on?